How to use Sonata User Bundle without email field?
I want to make registration and authorisation with Sonata User Bundle - not only for admins, for all users. 
But I want to do registration system without email.
In the model
Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User
    protected ?string $email = null;

    protected ?string $emailCanonical = null;

Both fields are nullable. Fine.
I have User class
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

#[ORM\Entity( repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table( name: 'users')]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['username'], message: 'There is already an account with this username')]
class User extends BaseUser
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    protected $id = null;
}

But when I generate migration, I have: 
... email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, email_canonical VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL
... UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E9A0D96FBF ON users (email_canonical)');

email and email_canonical not only not nullable, email_canonical has unique index
Where is writen that the are not nullable? How to fix that?
If I try use annotation in my User entity:
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    protected ?string $email = null;

I have error when I generate migration
Duplicate definition of column 'email' on entity 'App\Entity\User' in a field or discriminator column mapping.

Can I remove or ignore email and email_canonical?
UPD: No FOS in project. Symfony 6.4, php 8.3
